# Visual Studio Team Services: Single Build Definition for Multiple Branches

Tags: azure-devops

We are using **Visual Studio Team Services**.

We have a Prod-Branch which is builded by our Prod-Build-Definition and deployed by our Prod-Release-Definition to our Test / Integration and Production Environments.

With each Prod-Release deployed to the customer, we create a Prod-Rel-Version-x.x.x Branch from the Prod-Branch (in Case we need that for a Hotfix).

During the Sprint we are developping on a Dev-Branch which is builded by our Dev-Build-Definition and deployed by our Dev-Release-Definition to our DEV Environment for Developer Tests.

After the Sprint (or from time to time) the Dev-Branch is merged to the Main-Branch and then to the Prod-Branch. From there it is deployed to the different Stages for Testing by the customer.

When there is a Hotfix-Case, we fix the bug on the Prod-Rel-Version-x.x.x Branch and would like to reuse our existing Prod-Build-Definition to build this Hotfix-Version and deploy to the different stages by the existing Prod-Release-Definition for testing and going live with this version.

How can we reuse our Prod-Build-Definition with this different Branch (Prod-Rel-Version-x.x.x Branch instead of the Prod-Branch)?

When I look at the build definition, I think i would be possible, just be editing the Server Path (Repository > Mappings) from `$/NameOfOurApp/Prod` to `$/NameOfOurApp/Prod-Rel-Version-x.x.x)`...that should do the trick or not? But from what I read, it's not possible to use Build-Variables in Server Mappings, so I cannot change this variable for example in the Queue new Build Dialog...

What's the best way to accomplish my scenario?

Comment: This is sad :( . There should be a way to select "branch" from "Queue new build dialog".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do this is to create a single build definition which downloads all the branches. Then use variables in the tasks to select the version to build. This will become very messy (and slow) very fast.

Instead it's much easier to clone the build definition. Alternatively you can create a Build Definition Template from an existing build definition and use that to create a new Build Definition.

A much, much better solution however, is not to rely on so many branches.You only need the branch when you really need to make a hotfix, and you only need the stages branches when you have a lot of findings in higher stages. By improving teh way you work, you'll be able to get rid of the branches, simplifying the work for all.

### Update

VSTS and TFS 2018 now support the use of variables in the workspace definition.